# Importing AUTOCAD .dwg to Arcgis Symbols

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, symbology, autocad

My client has some symbol drawn in autocad.. they are saved in .dwg files.

How can I import them into ArcGIS symbols?

I have FME 2013, I am not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

For point symbols: Convert the symbols from .dwg to .emf. In ArcGIS you can use .emf as *picture marker symbol*.
Disadvantage: you can not change the color of the symbol.

Comment: sounds like a feasible idea, I will try it tomorrow :D will it have a transparent background?